# what does minify javascript mean? Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, minify

also,
an extra, not too irrelevant question,
you've an suggestions/resources/blogs to get up to speed on Backbone js libraries? Thanks.

Comment: A simple search would suffice, this isn't something that should be posted here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming). Backbone help: http://backbonetutorials.com/

Comment: To minify Javascript isn't something that is specific to Backbone.js, so you should explain what you mean with your question. It's too complex to be explained only in the title. Also, the question title should be just a title, not the complete question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

minify javascript is used to compress your javascript code: lets see an example:
this is a normal javascript function

```
function editField(id){
    //hello hello hello
        var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    var sum = a + b;

}
```

when you minify it looks like:

```
function editField(f){var d=1;var c=2;var e=d+c;};
```

when you minify the comments and spaces get deleted to improve the performance of your code

you can try this web tool to minify javascript
[link YUI Compressor](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/)